# Relation between beamwidths of E-plane and H-plane

Tags: communication-satellite, antenna

Is there any relation between E-plane and H-plane beamwidths of an antenna when steering in azimuth and elevation directions?

Comment: I can't figure out what it is you would like to know yet. You've asked a yes or no question, and the answer is almost certainly *Yes, there is some relation.* Also, I am not sure your question is about Space Exploration. There are many questions about antennas in [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and [Ham Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) and [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In fact, it seems I've asked one or more antenna questions in each of those sites! [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/286006/102305), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/302431/102305), [3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/306451/102305), [4](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/12899/8643), [5](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/12375/8643), [6](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458561/83380).